# Sync data in SQL Server 2014 with Oracle database12c

Tags: sql-server, oracle, data-synchronization

I have installed Oracle database 12c enterprise on my laptop.
How can I implement data synchronization between Oracle 12c and SQL Server 2014 that whenever an INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE or ... happend on SQL Server tables I can have it on my Oracle database automatically in the shortest time it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

1. Transactional replication: this has been around for quite some time
   and works nicely within its narrowly defined scenario.
   Unfortunately, the [use of non-SQL Server subscribers is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms151864(v=sql.120).aspx).
2. Change data capture + SSIS: this is the Microsoft recommended solution. It's a bit more involved than replication (to me anyway) but it's also more flexible. You can do some really powerful things with SSIS as the data mover, if you ever need it. Basic concepts [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315(v=sql.120).aspx) with a [detailed example here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/combining-cdc-and-ssis-incremental-data-loads).
3. Oracle solutions: you can also do it from the other end. Oracle has similar capabilities as SQL Server including their GoldenGate software. However, I believe it's extra $$$ for license. I don't think you'll need to tread this path but calling it out for completeness.

Comment: What about the "_Oracle Database Link_" and "_Heterogeneous Database Gateway_", Are these just another option for this issue or the cause of using them are different?

Comment: And also does "_Oracle Data Integrator_" do the same work or not?